# SDES algorithm purpose

Tags: tls, openssl

What is the purpose of SDES algorithm?  (Session Description Protocol Security Descriptions)

What are the problems in the way it exchanges keys?

I have tried to search about these quastions but i couldn't find any understandable reasons.
Please help me.

Comment: SDES (Session Description Protocol Security Descriptions) is used for key negotiation with the Secure Real Time Transport Protocol (SRTP).